# 'RobertaTokenizerFast' object has no attribute '_in_target_context_manager' error while loading data into custom NER model

Tags: python, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to load data into a custom NER model using spacy, I am getting an error:-

`'RobertaTokenizerFast' object has no attribute '_in_target_context_manager'`

however, it works fine with the other models.

Thank you for your time!!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue after upgrading my environment from {Python 3.9 + Spacy 3.3} to {Python 3.10 + Space 3.5}. Resolved this by upgrading and re-packaging the model.